# How can I delay the screen's password lock on my Stratosphere?

Tags: settings, lock-screens

I need my to have my screen be password locked, but I want it to kick in after only 5-10 minutes (i.e., if I lock my phone and unlock it a moment later, I *don't* want to have to put in my password again).

With my old Droid Pro it was very easy to set that up. On the Stratosphere it doesn't look like that option is available, so I keep having to put in my password every single time I go to unlock my phone. Am I missing something? Is there any way for me to do this?

Answer (score 1):

On the RAZR, it's separate from the display timeout. It's in "Security->Automatically lock". Not sure if that is unique to the RAZR or not.

If you have the SDK installed, it might be possible to push an alternate property with "adb shell setprop", but it would not be persistent across reboots.

Comment: With CM7.2 on my Droid 2, these settings are in *Settings -> CyanogenMod -> Lockscreen -> Unlock Options*. No such thing like *Security -> Automatically lock*. So it might well differ from device to device to Android Version to ROM to... we live in interesting times ;)